# Override methods of subActivity Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to override methods of a sub activity such as menu and also orientation on sub activity?
I am using Youtube player in my activity and I need to set the orientation of youtube player to landscape mode and also override its menu button. I have search through the net but couldn't find any solution, if any one know please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the Activity of an another application.